# How to create horizontal Listview in listview builder flutter

Tags: flutter, api, dart

I am using an API to build a movies application, I had a problem with making the**ListView** to be from left to right instead of up and dowm.I am trying to create a horizontal list view but it displayed not as expected. You can see how it looks in the **Image** bellow. It works with me usually but it my first time to do that inside a listview builder. How to fix that?

**Note**: I want the full screen to be vertical and this part only horizontal.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: 
      FutureBuilder(
        future: getData(),
        builder: (BuildContext context,AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
          if(snapshot.data == null){
            return Container(
              child: Center(
                child:CircularProgressIndicator() ,),);
          }
         

          else{
            return ListView.builder(
              
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length, 
               itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int i){

                 if(snapshot.data==null){
                   return Center(
                     child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                   );
                 }
                 else{
                 return Container(
                     height: 250,
                     child: Card(
                       child: ListView(
                         scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                         children: [
                           Image(image: NetworkImage(snapshot.data[i].poster))
                         ],
                       ),
                     ),
                   );
               }}
               );
               
          }
         
        }
      ,),
      
        ),
       );
     }
  }
```

Image

[image: here]

Comment: you want to display this list horizontly not vertically correct?

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil Yes, and when I use **scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal** the images go to the left as in the Picture above

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,`
inside the Listview.Builder to make it scroll horizontally and add a `width` for the container that's being returned.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its helpful to you . declare your `ListView.builder()` like below refer Listview [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html)

```
 Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 180,
            child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: 10,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
                return Container(
                  height: 50,
                  child: Card(
                    child: Image.network(
                      'https://tech.pelmorex.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/flutter.png',
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
```

Your result screen-> [image]